# Memory Error Parallel Python (Large data in parallel)

Tags: python, dictionary, parallel-processing

So I'm reading in a lot of data from a bunch of different files. One of the major speed hurdles is reading in data. The problem is that these files are in respective directories for their timestep which contains each variable for that timestep. So basically I have some functions that look like this.

```
def ReadFiles(path,points,directories,variables):
   data = {}
   for j in range(len(variables)):
      data[variables[j]] = np.zeros((len(timeDirs),numPts))
      for i in range(len(timeDirs)):
         tfile = str(path) + "/" + str(timeDirs[i])
         for j in range(len(variables)):
            job_server.submit(ReadData,(args,data,i,j),modules=("np",))
def ReadData(args):
   update path for the particular variable
   read in data from file
   data[variables[j]][i] = that data
```

**TLDR** Initialize the variables I have with numpy array into a dict. Then update the correct section inside another function that is parallelized.

I am using parallel python. I would like to move this code to a cluster at some point. The error I get is

```
  File "/home/steven/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pp.py", line 460, in submit
    sargs = pickle.dumps(args, self.__pickle_proto)
MemoryError: out of memory
```

From watching my memory usage I can see that the RAM goes up and then the swap starts to fill. Once both are full I get the error. From some reading I gather that each of these processes is being passed a new dictionary, which means updating in parallel isn't an option.

I will note that I DO NOT get this memory error when I run this in serial. So is there a good way to store or pass this data back to my dictionary using parallel? The final data is stored into an hdf5 file, but those don't seem to want to be open and written to in parallel.

Is there a good solution? How do you handle large data in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Reading data in parallel isn't likely to gain you anything since you're going to be I/O bound for as long as you're reading data, one file at a time or all at once. I'd switch it around to read the data serially but kick off the data setup (in parallel, natch) once each file is loaded. If you can load the entire file in one go then process it from memory you may see the performance gains you seek, at the expense of memory.

If you're exhausting memory then you'll need to figure out how to write out some of the data as you go so that you can drop those dictionary entries.

It might be feasible to memory map the files instead of explicitly reading them, then parallelizing the processing may make more sense, depending on the speed of your data processing versus the speed of I/O. That will allow you to leverage the OS's scheduling, assuming your data processing while loading takes long enough.

Comment: Dumping the dictionary once created is fast. The problem is reading in. I am reading in each data file independently. I'd just like to read these in in parallel. It does seem like a waste of computer power to just read in all my data in serial. 
How would I do a memory map?

Comment: Also, as said in my op I do not get a memory error in serial

Comment: You're not going to see any speed benefit by reading in parallel if you can saturate I/O in serial. That's why I suggested it. It's not a waste of computer power if you're already reading as much data as fast as possible.

Comment: Google helps a lot but you might find something useful in the mmap module that's part of Python.

Comment: When running in serial the CPU usage seems to only be at like 20-30%. So I'm really unsure how to make it go faster, which is really what I need. Though I would like to know how to properly share data across parallel so I can use it later

Comment: CPU usage will (hopefully) be low when reading and writing to disk because the disk is very slow compared to the CPU. You need to do other things while reading data if you want to get the CPU burning. E.g. read all of your data on one thread (without processing, without parsing, without assigning individual bytes) and then spawn jobs to process the data as files finish being read. Please try memory mapping all of your files and just see if that has any effect. It should pretty much just drop in.

Comment: I am having a hard time getting memory mapping to work properly. Each line changes in length and I need to do readline so that I can parse out some of the data. Basically take from 10 to 100000 inside the file, not caring about <10 >100000.

Comment: What about the example code in the Python documentation is failing? It uses readline explicitly.